# how to remove the whole array with commas and change option will return to the first option

Tags: jquery

Used jade with node.js for routes.js and Jquery

```
  .filter
     select.selectFilter
       option(value="") #{list}
```

JQuery

```
 var options = $('.selectFilter');
          console.log("1 " + options);
          if(options.length){
            var split = options.text().split(',');
            console.log("2 " + split);
            options.empty();
            if(split.length > 1){
              for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
               options.append('<option value=?list=' + split[i] + '>' + split[i] + '</option>');
              }
            }
          }
          $(options).on('change', function(e){
            var url = $(this).val();
            window.location = url;
          });
```

routes.js

```
var list = ['a','b','c']
```

I tried to use options.empty() which shows A, B, C in one line while others are split as expected. 
For example: 
A, B, C
A
B
C

When reloading the page, it would still show A, B, C (jumpy) before showing the first option "A". Also when select any of the options, it still shows the first option "A". Couldn't figure how to remove "A, B, C" totally. 
Also not sure why change option will return to the first option, not selected option? How to set option selected?

Help appreciated.

**Updates**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0jcahdfp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mistake here:

```
options.append('<option value=?list=' + split[i] + '>' + split[i] + '</option>');
```

Change it to:

```
options.append('<option value="?list=' + split[i] + '">' + split[i] + '</option>');
```

Comment: thanks for correction but it still shows ABC on reload or select menu. update post with jsfiddle. it is not as same as my local machine.

Comment: weird.. i tried to save but it showed me empty page. hmmm. i will redo the jsfiddle later.